# Opening select options on click

Tags: javascript, html, select, onclick

Is there a way to open select options onclick, instead of having the `<select>` and `<option>` elements?

```
<label onclick = 'openSelectOptions()'> Click Me </label>
```

Comment: It's unclear from the question, what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to trigger the click event for the select list from somewhere else?

Comment: @ShekharChikara This is on mobile. I want the select list to be hidden, and triggered on click of the label.

Comment: @ShekharChikara I only need the function to trigger the select list, the rest I can figure out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, but does not work in all browser.
It works for me on Google Chrome

```js
function openSelectOptions(){
  var element = $("#open")[0];
  var worked = false;
  if (document.createEvent) {
      var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
  } else if (element.fireEvent) {
      worked = element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
  }
  if (!worked) {
      alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="open">
    <option>nothing</option>
    <option>something</option>
    <option>anything</option>
</select>
<button onclick = 'openSelectOptions()'> Click Me </button>
```